# Is it possible to use virtualenvwrapper with multiple WORKON directories?

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Ive discovered virtualenvwrapper recently and want to try it, but I usually create virtualenvs in project directories, so I have not single WORKON directory. Is it possible to attach existing vierualenvs located in different directories to virtualenvwrapper?

Comment: I used to solve the same problem. But I discovered that it much more easy to recreate my virtualenvs using virtualenvwrapper instead of moving them around.